# SQL Database design - Large permission table

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have a interesting issue with the design for user permissions on our existing database.

We have a large table with well over 10 million records that the powers that be now want individual permissions placed on.

I immediately think OK, create a new table, each user has its own column and access is done with a bit value.

```
           [U1]  [U2]  [U3]  [U4] etc.
=============================================
Record 1 |  1  |  0  |  1  |  0  |
Record 2 |  0  |  0  |  1  |  1  |
Record 3 |  0  |  1  |  1  |  0  |
Record 4 |  1  |  0  |  1  |  1  |
```

Then I was told to expect 300 users as we allow more access to the database which would mean 300 columns :/

So can anyone out there think of a better way to do this? Any thoughts or suggestions will be gratefully received.

Comment: having 1 column for each user is a terrible idea. You need to normalise it. If you *do* need this type of design I would suggest 3 columns. A `UserID` column, a `RecordID` column and a `Persmission` column (a `bit`). That scales *far* better. Then, if a User doesn't have that permission, it can also be assumed it's a `0`, unless you are using explicit `DENY` and `ALLOW` styles.

Comment: Are there any communalities in users? How do you decide who can see which record - if you have 10M records, how on earth do you populate the "Alice can see records 1, 2 and 34, Bob can see 2, 34 and 1001" data? Can you introduce the concept of "group"? Is permission binary (yes/no), or do permissions involve operations like read/modify/delete?

Comment: I understand your point Larnu, I am simply concerned that I end up with a table with 3 billion records (300 * 10,000,000) that controls permissions.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have "records" @Sabs , it has Columns and Rows. And why would you think that a well indexed normalised table would be slower than a denormalised, and therefore hard to index, table containing the "same" data? if you're going to have 300 Billion data points (a single column and row value) in a normalised table, you would in a denormalised table too; so you're point is somewhat redundant in regards to storage as well. Especially as (as I mentioned) you can likely *assume* that a lack of a row means `0` too; meaning you save significant space with a normalised design.

Comment: Hi Neville, 3 Permission settings: no access/ read/ modify. I am pushing for us to group permissions by the record structure (about 5000 different groups in the 10m record table) which would then allow it to be normalized like Larnu suggested but I just want to make sure there is no better approach. The powers that be still want it done by each user which is simply horrible :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I mention in the comments, use a normalised approach. Considering that the value for the allow/dey is a `bit`, you could actually just do with with 2 columns, the User's ID and the Record's ID:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.UserAllowPermissions (UserID int,
                                       RecordID int);
ALTER TABLE dbo.UserAllowPermissions
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_UserRecordPermission
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (UserID,RecordID);
```

Then you can `INSERT` the data you already have above like below:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.UserAllowPermissions (UserID,
                                      RecordID)
VALUES (1, 1),
       (1, 4),
       (2, 3),
       (3, 1),
       (3, 2),
       (3, 3),
       (3, 4),
       (4, 2),
       (4, 4);
```

If you want to revoke the permission of a User, then just delete the relevant row. For example, say you want to revoke the permission for User 3 to Record 4:

```
DELETE
FROM dbo.UserAllowPermissions
WHERE UserID = 3
  AND RecordID = 4;
```

And, unsurprisingly, if you want to grant a user permission, just `INSERT` the row:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.UserAllowPermissions (UserID, RecordID)
VALUES(5,1);
```

Which would grant the User with the ID of 5 access to the Record with an ID of 1.

Comment: I think this is the right approach if you can't model "group", but it needs an indicator of which permission applies (read only/modify).

Comment: I also think you might explain how a query for "record_id = $1 and user_id = $2" is much easier to optimize than "record-id = $1 and user_id_column = $2" - a single index in the first case, 300 indices in the second!

Comment: Including the Clustered Primary Key kind of touches on this, @NevilleKuyt, as it shows how simple it is to make the index on the table.

Comment: Thanks for your input guys. I was really hoping there was some new magic way I didn't know but I guess there isn't.